# Adding font borders to CSS code

Tags: html, css, fonts, border

As the title suggests, I'm trying to add font borders to the text I have in a page I'm making. The background has a lot of reds, greens, yellows and blacks so a single colour really wouldn't suffice. [Here is the code.](http://pastebin.com/ja9Ds0sB)

I know I can do something with webkit like this:

```
h1 { -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black; }
```

But since it's not supported on browsers I'm stuck on square one.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe consider using a text-shadow instead? They're cross-browser, and in my opinion, they look really cool.

Comment: Define what you mean by “font borders”, include the *relevant* code in the question itself, and explain what is relevant in it.

Answer (score 3):

For a 1 pixel stroke, `text-shadow` would do:

```
text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

You can only use `text-stroke` on webkit browsers (Chrome, safari, etc)

Source: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke)

But like other poeple answered, you can use `text-shadow` instead

```
p {    
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk2PD/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/text-shadow.en.html

see this link may help

it adds text shadow to letters if you dont want feather then keep value to 0px will give you border around text